# IIS FTP Server connect local but not remote

Tags: firewall, ftp, iis

Hi everyone Im' trying to connect to FTP Server from an android app, but it doesn't work, but that's not the problem, the problem is either I can't access to FTP server since CMD or browser, I'm using an API that access to this, and when I run it local with the FTP server active in the same PC works, but when I upload the FTP server to other PC doesn't work, both PC are in the same ethernet, I tried to deactivate the firewall in the PC where I run the API but still the problem ¿What's my problem?

This is the FTP Server configuration, the anonymous autentication is active, and the rules are allow all users:

[rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5mBD.png)

[autentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi15d.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload the FTP server to other PC"? You need to install and configure the FTP server on the other PC.

Comment: I mean, I try to upload a file to a server with FTP server, but my problem was the ip address thanks